# Is there a way to run e2e test for deployed Angular App?

Tags: angular, cypress, e2e

Depolyed alpha version of the app for demo purposes, now I did e2e tests on local server, but I want to do some on current live version to see real time results...is it possible? If yes, how?

So far I only did basic tests using cypress

Comment: Assuming you can access the live version yourself, it should just be a matter of setting the URL to point at your live server. What is making you wonder whether this is possible?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior in my cy.config once i change the baseUrl it always goes to localhost, not sure wether how to fix that